# I have a conflict issue with this code, it still wants to remove the value

Tags: c#

I have a conflict issue with this code, it still wants to remove the value "StateFlags0200" or "StateFlags0300" even if it does not exist in the Windows registry and yet my logic seems to me correct.

```
enter code here
```

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {
        #region Block #1

        if ((checkBox1.Checked == true) & (radioButton1.Checked == true))
        {
            RegistryKey KeyBase = Registry.LocalMachine;
            RegistryKey KeyPath = KeyBase.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Active Setup Temp Folders", true);
            KeyPath.SetValue("StateFlags0100", Convert.ToInt32("2", 16), RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            KeyPath.Close();

        }
        else
        {

            RegistryKey KeyBase = Registry.LocalMachine;
            RegistryKey KeyPath = KeyBase.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Active Setup Temp Folders", true);
            KeyPath.DeleteValue("StateFlags0100");
            KeyPath.Close();
        }

        if ((checkBox1.Checked == true) & (radioButton2.Checked == true))
        {
            RegistryKey KeyBase = Registry.LocalMachine;
            RegistryKey KeyPath = KeyBase.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Active Setup Temp Folders", true);
            KeyPath.SetValue("StateFlags0200", Convert.ToInt32("2", 16), RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            KeyPath.Close();

        }
        else
        {

            RegistryKey KeyBase = Registry.LocalMachine;
            RegistryKey KeyPath = KeyBase.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Active Setup Temp Folders", true);
            KeyPath.DeleteValue("StateFlags0200");
            KeyPath.Close();
        }

        if ((checkBox1.Checked == true) & (radioButton3.Checked == true))
        {
            RegistryKey KeyBase = Registry.LocalMachine;
            RegistryKey KeyPath = KeyBase.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Active Setup Temp Folders", true);
            KeyPath.SetValue("StateFlags0300", Convert.ToInt32("2", 16), RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            KeyPath.Close();

        }
        else
        {

            RegistryKey KeyBase = Registry.LocalMachine;
            RegistryKey KeyPath = KeyBase.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Active Setup Temp Folders", true);
            KeyPath.DeleteValue("StateFlags0300");
            KeyPath.Close();
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
RegistryKey KeyBase = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey KeyPath = KeyBase.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Active Setup Temp Folders", true);
KeyPath.DeleteValue("StateFlags0100", false);
KeyPath.Close();
```

The default behavior for DeleteValue is to throw if the value is not found. To change that, a second version of the method exists, that accepts a second boolean parameter that explicitly states whether an exception shall be thrown if the value is not there. More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.deletevalue(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: It works but it removes the initial value when I change from radiobutton1 to another. These are the profiles I'm trying to make. In the registry, it should not delete the other "StateFlags".

Comment: The easy solution would be to create 3 tabs and triple my checkboxes with the same names but not the same IDs in the code and remove my radiobuttons. Would there be another solution? 
Excuse for my bad english.

Comment: How does it remove "the initial value"? I can't see from the above code how that is possible.

Comment: I do not understand. 
But, I use 3x my checkbox with another condition that should not in priciple influence.

Comment: Finally, I opted for profiles 3 tabs. That makes a lot of checkboxes. But, I had no choice in the complexity of my conditions
Thank you